RAD (Remote Access Descriptors ) in OPSS schema
[ Remote Access Descriptor (RAD) entries in Oracle Platforms Security Services (OPSS). - when we create RAD in the EM console, where exactly it stored ? in which file and which location  in weblogic ? as we have 250 user and i wanted to have backup of that file so something goes wring then can be restored. so
correct table in OPSS where RAD entry is stored..is this stored in DB ? can we take the backup of that one ?
we added RAD entry in EM console and wanted to know where it is stored ? how we can take back up of it to restore in case any issue.

RAD data is stored in the OPSS tables in the database.  If you don't recall, when the domain is created you run the Repository Creation Utility, which creates a set of schemas in the DB.  One of those schemas is for OPSS.
